# Can a .NET 5 project be set up to always build with release configuration?

Tags: .net-core, f#, msbuild, project

I have a small .NET 5 project whose project file is shown below.

This project will be used to run performance benchmarks against my main project.  As such, I'd like to always build it with the `release` configuration.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#options) for the `-c` option of `dotnet build` command does say the following, but I haven't found any reference to it in the [project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#project-files) section:

> The default for most projects is Debug, but you can override the build
> configuration settings in your project.

Is there a way to specify this in the project file rather than having to write `dotnet build -c release` each time I run it?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\Domain\Domain.fsproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add `<Configuration>Release</Configuration>` to the property group. See the [corresponding MSBuild documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thank you.  For future reference, I also had to update the project reference as follows: `<ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\Domain\Domain.fsproj" SetConfiguration="Configuration=Release"/>`

Comment: ...and for some reason I also had to add `<Optimize>true</Optimize>` in the property group as well, to stop BenchmarkDotNet complaining.